# HTML 5 Mobile App platform for salesforce integration

Tags: mobile

Note: We do not want to use salesforce1 app (yes we do not want to use it.)

I am planning to create simple mobile app which just has single page and it will pull data from salesforce and write back to salesforce via rest and Oauth.

What is the best way to implement this quickly.

Note: We do not want to use salesforce1 app (yes we do not want to use it.)

Comment: What are your requirements? Why do they exclude Salesforce1? Lots of solutions out there, even deploy a Sencha Touch application onto a Force.com Site in your org. Very curious :-)

Comment: @bigassforce Thanks for comment, we do not want to get that whole options come with Salesforce app, we want custom and simple one page with focusing on use case we are looking at. can you please give me more details about Sencha on salesforce site, i am curious about this option now.

Comment: @bigassforce Curious, have you reliably got Sencha Touch working in SF1 Mobile, we are struggling with all sorts of IFRAME issues. We have even tried wrapping in Lightning Components, while this solves the IFRAME issues, it presents a host of others (documented in the Lightning Chatter group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Salesforce Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK). When you create a 'hybrid' app, it gives you a basic app that authenticates the user and does a simple API call from JavaScript. You should be able to adapt that to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, will start exploring it now.